# Run the game when minimaize (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play the game when the mobile user has minimized the game, because I have a built-in timer.

I used the code

```
Application.runInBackground = true;
```

but it does not work on Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android doesn't allow applications to run in the background like this.

What you should do instead is track how much time has passed between the application being hidden and the user re-opening it - and use the time passed combined with the previous game state to calculate the new state. To the user this will give the impression that the game has been running the entire time without actually doing so.

So if some value in the game increases by 5 every second, you'd increment it by 5 * how many seconds have elapsed.

Comment: Tanks.But 
How can I find the minimalized game?
And how do you know if the game is open?

Do you know the code for minimizing and opening the game?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html - using OnApplicationPause and OnApplicationFocus you know when the application has been hidden and resumed. When the application is paused you should also persist the current time to storage in case the user quits the application entirely and check that value when your application is restarted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run apps in the background in Android, it doesn't matter if you say `Application.runInBackground = true;` it won't run in the background.

Comment: You **can**. It's called "service" but the code to run in the background must be written in Java instead of C# Unity which Unity uses.